# Mapping a class hierarchy to a database

Tags: python, django, database-design

#### Prerequisite

I want to implement abstract inheritance:

```py
class Base(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta: 
        abstract = True


class ChildA(Base):
    foo = models.CharField()


class ChildB(Base):
    bar = models.CharField()
```

For multiple reasons I need a db representation of the hierarchy of these classes. So I want to create a model like this one (`left` and `right` attributes allow us to identify instance's place in the node tree):

```py
class Node(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField()
    model_name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    right = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    left = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

#### The Problem

I need something similar to this:

```py
class Base(models.Model):
    ...
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        app_label = cls._meta.app_label
        model_name = cls._meta.model_name
        parent_id = ? # I am not sure how do we get parent's id for now, but it should be manageable 
        obj = Node.objects.create('app_label'=app_label, 'model_name'=model_name, 'parent'=parent_id)
        obj.save()
```

So, as we subclass an abstract model, a new node is created that represents this new model in the hierarchy tree. Unfortunately, it won't work. It seems `__init_subclass__` is invoked before `Model` class is properly initialized, so `cls._meta.model_name` will return incorrect value (parent's `model_name`, in fact). Can we bypass this (or use some other hook)?

#### Other concerns

I am not sure if this whole idea is sensible. I previously used multi-table inheritance, but at some point SQL queries became really ugly, so I am trying to fix it by using abstract models instead. But we still need to tie models to each other, a node tree seems appealing. This way I get a concrete model to manage multiple tables simultaneously, like this:

```py
class NodeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        root = self._get_root_node()
        fields = root._meta.get_fields() 
        field_names = [field.name for field in fields]
        descendants = list(self._get_descendant_models(root))
        queryset_list = []
        for model in descendants:
            qs = model.objects.values(*field_names)
            annotated_qs = qs.annotate(
                resource_model=models.Value(
                    root._meta.model_name,
                    models.CharField(max_length=120)
                )
            )
            queryset_list.append(annotated_qs)

        if len(queryset_list) > 1:
            merged_queryset = queryset_list[0].union(*queryset_list[1:])
        elif len(queryset_list) == 1:
            merged_queryset = queryset_list[0]
        else:
            merged_queryset = None 

        return merged_queryset
```

This is not how managers are supposed to be used, I guess, so I am not sure if it's fine.
I don't want to focus on this, it's mainly to give a better idea what I am aiming for. But if you let me know whether you think it's fine or not, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType) module that can be directly used for this purpose but you would need to do some extra things to get what you need.

You need to handle app ready method that's defined by AppConfig class. The problem is you need to handle the App ready method for each app, instead of adding this code to every app you can just add this as a base class.

```
class BaseAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def add_or_update_node(self, model, super_classes):
        # assuming Node model is defined in a separate app called node
        from node.models import Node
        super_classes = super_classes[::-1]
        super_classes.append(model)
        prev_node = None
        for super_class in super_classes:
            node, _ = Node.objects.get_or_create(app_label=super_class._meta.app_label,
                                                 model_name=super_class._meta.model_name)
            if node.parent is None and prev_node is not None:
                node.parent = prev_node
                node.save()
            prev_node = node

    def ready(self):
        import inspect
        // if variable is not set than do not do anything 
        if os.getenv('CREATE_NODE') is None:
            return
        for model_name, model in self.models.items():
            super_classes = []
            for clazz in inspect.getmro(model):
                if clazz == Model or clazz == object or clazz == model:
                    continue
                super_classes.append(clazz)
            # no super class
            if len(super_classes) == 0:
                continue

            self.add_or_update_node(model, super_classes)
```

This handles only the case when you have a single hierarchy model, what about the case when a model is extending from multiple abstract models, left for the op to work upon.

You need to extend this class in your apps.py file.

```
class CoreConfig(BaseAppConfig):
    name = 'Core'

    def ready(self):
        super(CoreConfig, self).ready()
```